# How to skip the row in a .csv file that causes a ValueError when iterating in Python

Tags: python, csv

In my program I iterate over the rows of a .csv file and perform an operation on each one. In some cases the program is terminated by a ValueError. When this occurs I would like to print an error message and then move onto the next line, rather than having the program stop. Here is the code that iterates over the file:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
for row in reader:
        strrow = str(row)
        getInfo(strrow)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP should [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Why are you taking a perfectly useful list and turning it back into a string? Don't you end up re-parsing it in `getInfo`? It seems likely that the `ValueError` is coming from `getInfo`; why not handle it there, where you have more information about the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'd think this is the typical use case for a try-except block:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    for row in reader:
        try:
            strrow = str(row)
            getInfo(strrow)
        except ValueError:
            print('Error!')
```

Comment: You need to indent the code inside the `with` block.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is using a try-catch block. What it basically does is executing the code in the try-block, and when an exception occurs (and there is a matching catch-block), it executes the block.

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    try:
        for row in reader:
            strrow = str(row)
            getInfo(strrow)
    except ValueError:
        print "Oops!  That was no valid row..."
```

Source:
[Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct to identify `try: except:` as the code to use here, but have applied it incorrectly. To avoid catching errors you actually need to hear about (and, in this case, to let you actually keep iterating over the `reader`), only the line whose errors you explicitly want to handle needs to be wrapped in a `try`. As there's not much that can't be made a string, I'd guess that means:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
for row in reader:
        strrow = str(row)
        try:
            getInfo(strrow)
        except ValueError:
            print("Couldn't process line: {0}".format(strrow))
```

However, this does bring up a few questions:

1. Why not pass the actual list to `getInfo`? It seems pointless to use `csv` to parse the file from strings to lists, then turn the lists back into strings, when you could actually pass the list (and probably save some parsing).
2. Why not put the error handling inside `getInfo`? Within that function you know exactly what is going wrong with which part of the line (and can therefore provide a much more helpful message to the user); outside, all you know is that *something* went wrong.

If you made both those changes, the code here would be much simpler:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
map(getInfo, reader)
```